# Difference between functions

Tags: php, function

What is the difference between functions like: `require_once`, `require`, `include` and `include_once`?

Thanks.

Comment: See the respective manual pages for [`require_once`](http://php.net/require_once), [`require`](http://php.net/require), [`include`](http://php.net/include) and [`include_once`](http://php.net/include_once).

Answer (score 4):

Just check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php):

> The [include()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

---

> The [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) statement includes and evaluates the specified file
>   during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the
>   include() statement, with the only difference being that if the code
>   from a file has already been included, it will not be included again.
>   As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

---

> [require()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) is identical to include() except upon failure it will also
>   produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will
>   halt the script whereas include() only emits a warning (E_WARNING)
>   which allows the script to continue.

---

> The [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) statement is identical to require() except PHP will
>   check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include
>   (require) it again.